# Configure LXC with additional IP ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, ip, lxc

I'm still looking for answer on my question. I have a dedicated server with ubuntu server 14.04, and 2 public ip. I want to add 1 public ip per 1 lxc. I think i've tried everything and nothing helped me :(.

After install fresh system I got default:

```
root@h0st:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static
address 94.23.237.216
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 94.23.237.0
broadcast 94.23.237.255
gateway 94.23.237.254
```

LXC configuration:

```
root@h0st:~# cat /var/lib/lxc/Oksymoron/config
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/Oksymoron/rootfs
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/Oksymoron/fstab
lxc.utsname = Oksymoron lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = eth0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:e0:1b:5d
```

```
cat /var/lib/lxc/Oksymoron/rootfs/etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And as I mentioned I got 2 additional ip's: 91.121.239.228/32, 188.165.139.63/32

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of creating or configuring multiple IP addresses on a single network interface is called IP aliasing. IP aliasing is very useful for setting up multiple virtual sites on Apache using one single network interface with different IP addresses on a single subnet network.

The main advantage of using this IP aliasing is, you don’t need to have a physical adapter attached to each IP, but instead you can create multiple or many virtual interfaces (aliases) to a single physical card.

Here I have an interface called eth0, the default interface for the Ethernet device. If you’ve attached second Ethernet device, then there would be an eth0:1 device and so on for each device you’ve attached.

Example:

root@h0st:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static

    address 94.23.237.216
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 94.23.237.0
    broadcast 94.23.237.255
    gateway 94.23.237.254

auto eth0:1 iface eth0:1 inet static

    address 91.131.239.228
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 91.131.239.0
    broadcast 91.131.239.255
    gateway 91.131.239.254
```